# How can I import a block with a logical code in Xcos?

Tags: matlab, simulink, scilab, xcos

I would like to make a block with this logical, where y1 is the output and u1 is the input. See:

```
if u1>18 then 
    y1=0.05;
elseif u1<-18 then y1=-0.05;
else y1=0
end
```

I tried to use the 'Switch Dynamic' block, but it only accepts a single input higher than a certain value and cannot handle two comparison values.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked in XCos. However, I have some experience in Graphical Simulation tool called Simulink which I believe is similar to XCos.  In simulink, you can use MATLAB block wherein you can add your matlab script similar to one shown in your above post. No of inputs for the block is same as the no of input params defined in the script

Similarly XCos may also have  script block feature, where in you can create conditional block  using multiple inputs. Please check how to use Script block

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).